# Matlab - using values from two matrices to alter a third

Tags: matlab, comparison, lookup

I have a matrix A which contains values 0-100. Matrix B (same number of rows, but only two columns) has values 0 or 1 in its second column. Matrix C has the same number of entries as Matrix A, but just 0 or 1.

I'll assume C starts full of zeros. If there is a 1 in the second column of B, then I want to have a 1 in the same row in C, for every position where there is a value in the corresponding position in A. However, I can't work out how to get this. I've tried using the for loop, but it doesn't seem to be doing what I want.

i.e.

```
A =
10 10 10
10 10 10
0  20 10

B =
1 0
2 0
3 1
```

I want to have C:

```
C =
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 1 1
```

Very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find desired rows using B:

```
>> B(:, 2) == 1

ans =

     0
     0
     1
```

Find possible values from A:

```
>> A ~= 0

ans =

     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     0     1     1
```

Put it all together by `and`ing using `bsxfun`:

```
>> bsxfun(@and, B(:, 2) == 1, A ~= 0)

ans =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     1     1
```